# I want to transpose a list of strings but I get TypeError

Tags: python, arrays

suppose I have this list of strings

```
li=['efh','opd','qst']
```

I want to "transpose" them so they look like this

```
li=['eoq','fps','hdt']
```

Here's the code I proposed but I get a typeError

```
previous=''

for i in range (len(li)):
    for j in range (len(li[0])):
        list2[j][i]=previous+list[i][j]
        previous=list2[j][i]
    previous=''
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a number of issues, the specific error is due to a typo:

```
list2[j][i]=previous+list[i][j]
                     ^^^^
```

`list` is a built in type and doesn't support indexing.
Additionally, `list2` is undefined and python's `str` is immutable so you can't assign to a `str` index.
Also changing `li` during iteration would make later iterations produce the wrong results so would recommend creating a new list to hold the result.

A working copy of your code would look like:

```
In []:
li=['efh','opd','qst']
new_li = []
for i in range(len(li[0])):
    r = ''
    for j in range(len(li)):
        r += li[j][i]
    new_li.append(r)
new_li

Out[]:
['eoq', 'fps', 'hdt']
```

Note: python's `zip()` would do this for you:

```
In []:
li=['efh','opd','qst']
[''.join(s) for s in zip(*li)]

Out[]:
['eoq', 'fps', 'hdt']
```

Comment: Feedback welcome, silent voting down, doesn't help me improve.

Comment: @AChampion Yes, completely incomprehensible action. A good and working answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can go through this.

```
li=['efh','opd','qst']
new_list = []
for i in range(len(li[0])):
    # maiking a list with its index element and convert it into string.
    new_string = ''.join([ls[i] for ls in li])
    # appending the new_string int new_list
    new_list.append(new_string)
print(new_list)

# output : ['eoq', 'fps', 'hdt']
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Helped me. But I needed to improve since not all of my strings have the same length.   Therefore line 5 was changed to 'new_string = ''.join([(ls[i] if i<len(ls) else ''  ) for ls in li])   '